# From bash to ksh - script throws errors but still works

Tags: ksh

I have created a simple BASH script that checks every hour for the presence of a file on a remote server. It worked error-free until I was asked to move it to a server that runs KSH.

The portion of code that errors-out is this one:

```
connect_string=$UID@$SERVER:$srcdir/$EVENTFILE
result=`sftp -b "$connect_string" 2>&1`

if [ echo "$result" | grep "not found" ]; then
  echo "not found"
else
  echo "found"
fi
```

These are the errors it throws:

```
-ksh: .[51]: [: ']' missing
grep: ]: No such file or directory
found
```

It still runs though and confirms that the file I am polling for is there but I need to fix this. I changed the if statement like so

```
if [[ echo "$result" | grep "not found" ]]; then
```

but it fails right away with this error

```
-ksh: .: syntax error: `"$result"' unexpected
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `if` checks the return code of the last command executed for the list provided. so `if echo "$result" | grep "not found" ; then` should be sufficient. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic syntax assumptions for `if` are incorrect.  The old `[...]` syntax, calls the `test` builtin, and `[[...]]` is for textual pattern matching.

As @shelter's comment, the correct syntax is:

```
connect_string="$UID@$SERVER:$srcdir/$EVENTFILE"
result=`sftp -b "$connect_string" 2>&1`

if echo "$result" | grep "not found" ; then
    echo "not found"
else
    echo "found"
fi
```

But this is an unnecessary use of the external `grep` program, you can use shell text comparison:

```
if [[ $result == *not\ found* ]] ; then
    echo "not found"
else
    echo "found"
fi
```

(tested with bash and ksh)

Your solution:

```
EXIT=`echo $?`
if [ $EXIT != 0 ]
then
    ...
fi
```

Can be improved.  First, if you are going to do an arithmetic comparison, then use `((...))`, not `test`, and I can't figure out why you have the `EXIT` variable:

```
if (( $? != 0 ))
then
    ...
fi
```

But to go full circle, you actually only need:

```
if sftp -b "$connect_string" 2>&1 
then
    ...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$result" | grep "not found"
#capture exit status code from previous command ie grep.
if [[ $? == 0 ]]
than
 echo "not found"
else
 echo "found"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're struggling with a basic tenet of bash/ksh control structures.

Between the `if` and the `then` keywords, the shell expects one or more *commands*, with
the last command in the series deciding how the `if` statement is processed.

The square brackets are only needed if you actually need to perform a *comparison*.  Internally they are equivalent to the `test` command - if the comparison succeeds, it
results in an exit status of 0.

Example:

```
$ [ a == a ]
$ echo $?
0
$ [ a == b ]
$ echo $?
1
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
$ test a == a
$ echo $?
0
$ test a == b
$ echo $?
1
```

Answer (score -1):

I changed my approach to this.

```
connect_string=$UID@$SERVER:$srcdir/$EVENTFILE
result=`sftp "$connect_string" 2>&1`
EXIT=`echo $?`
if [ $EXIT != 0 ]
then
                        echo "file not found"
                        exit 1
else
                        echo "file found"
                        exit 0
fi
```

It takes care of my problem. Thanks to all.

Comment: Read the answer from @cdarke : His `if sftp -b "$connect_string" 2>&1; then` ... is all you really need.